# How to extract specific content from the string value in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to extract the date and time values from a string.

string_value :

```
List = ['D:/Python/sfusd_to_hipSfusd/reports_api/meet/activity/dt=2020-10- 
02/api_batch_id=00db1d37-96bb-4beb-a8db-0e62443f5d81/2020-10-02 13-34-55.json']
```

Output that I need :

```
2020-10-02 13-34-55
```

---

Could anyone help me to solve this in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us what you have tried and format your question appropriately (ie make code appear code).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to get the right pattern

```
import re
re.findall("([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", s)
```

Output:

```
['2020-10-02 13-34-55']
```

Comment: @Sakthi: kindly accept the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Of course I don't know the format of the strings you want to extract the date from. But this is a rough idea on how to do it. Note that the index `-1` is the last position, or equivalently the first from right.

```
s =  'D:/Python/sfusd_to_hipSfusd/reports_api/meet/activity/dt=2020-10-02/api_batch_id=00db1d37-96bb-4beb-a8db-0e62443f5d81/2020-10-02 13-34-55.json'
parts_split_by_slash = s.split("/")
after_last_slash = parts_split_by_slash[-1]
part_before_dot = after_last_slash.split(".")[0]
print(part_before_dot)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.basename` to get filename . then you need to use `os.path.splitext` to separate extension from filename

Code:

```
import os

string_value = ["D:/Python/sfusd_to_hipSfusd/reports_api/meet/activity/dt=2020-10- 02/api_batch_id=00db1d37-96bb-4beb-a8db-0e62443f5d81/2020-10-02 13-34-55.json"]
for str in string_value:
    file = os.path.basename(string_value[0])
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    print(f_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your string appears to be a path value

You can also utilize [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

```
>>> s =  'D:/Python/sfusd_to_hipSfusd/reports_api/meet/activity/dt=2020-10-02/api_batch_id=00db1d37-96bb-4beb-a8db-0e62443f5d81/2020-10-02 13-34-55.json'

>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.split(s)[1])[0]
'2020-10-02 13-34-55'
>>>
```